# Syntax error: pop

Tags: assembly, x86, masm

```
wczytaj_do_EAX PROC
    push ebx
    push ecx
    push edx
    push esi
    push edi

    pop edi
    pop esi
    pop edx
    pop ecx
    pop ebx

    ret
wczytaj_do_EAX ENDP
```

Error:

```
A2008 Syntax error: pop
```

I'm using visual studio 2017 and this is only test code. I'm really confused.

Comment: Are you building 64-bit code?  32-bit operand size isn't possible for x86-64.  **Do you get an error for every push/pop line, or just one of them?  If so, which one?**  Are you sure you don't have any non-ASCII hidden characters messing up your source code?  All of those source lines look correct for x86 32-bit.

Comment: I'm getting error only when i want to pop to ecx register

Comment: Try deleting that line and typing it again.  (and/or look at a hexdump of your source file)  You probably have a hidden character (like non-ASCII whitespace) in your source somewhere.

Comment: If this was in fact a hidden character that some how appeared when using the IDE, then I think this qualifies for the visual-studio tag. Were you able to resolve the issue by retyping the line in the editor?